# IN SSRS How to get Current week Thursday date

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder, powerbi-paginated-reports

I want to get current week thursday name at all time for example today date at the time of asking this question is `12/02/2024 (uk format).` I want to return the thursday's date `(11/01/2024)` going forward the date should dynamically change
i wrote this expression

**=Today.AddDays(-(Weekday(Today) - 1) + IIf(Weekday(Today) < 6, 4, 11))**
it is giving me error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that if the report is run on a Thursday then you want the date returned to be the same Thursday then the following should work.

This assumes your system settings default to the weekday starting on a Sunday (weekday = 1) and therefore Thursday is weekday 5, if not just adjust the 5 to match your setup, or pass in the weekday start as an argument to the Weekday() function.

```
=Today.AddDays( 5 - Weekday(Today) )
```